# VFS: cannot open root device "nvme1n1p4" or unknown-block & Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, boot, grub, upgrade

I was in the process of upgrading my Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04. Unfortunately, I made an error during the upgrade process. I decided to restart the computer hoping it would fix the problem. Now I'm unable to log in to Ubuntu. The specific error I encounter is:

```
VFS: cannot open root device "nvme1n1p4" or unknown-block
Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

[image]

How can I access a terminal under these circumstances to fix this mess? What are the steps I should do to fix my ubuntu?

Comment: Could you describe the error you made during the upgrade process? Anyway I guess you'd have to boot with a live/rescue image in order to recreate the boot. But if the system is in a bad state (because of the problems during upgrade) this might not work better.